# python 2.7 line.index if statement for a multiplication table

Tags: python-2.7, if-statement

```
lines = [[str(i * j) for i in xrange(1, 13)] for j in xrange(1, 13)]

for line in lines:
    for num in line:
        if line.index(num):
            print ' ' * (3 - len(num)) + num,
        else:
            print ' ' * (2 - len(num)) + num,
    print
```

I am trying to understand why the `else` statement pertains to the first line
 and the `line.index(num)` pertains to remaining lines.

Comment: can you edit the post and post the code formatted so we can read and help

Comment: please explain any problem you are getting, clearly.

Comment: @Bhansa. It is not a good idea to edit code formatting like this, especially with Python-based questions. The formatting could have been the cause of the problem.

Comment: Thanks @SiHa I'll keep this in mind.

Answer (score 0):

As your `if` statement is not comparing the return of `line.index(num)` against anything, returning any non zero value will satisfy the condition and returning a value of 0 will result in the `else` statement.

`line.index(num)` returns 0 if `num` is the first entry in `line` and so only acts on the first entry from each `line` in `lines`.